# How to add a space between bootstrap multi-select checkbox and its label

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add `20px` of space between a checkbox and its label on a bootstrap multi-select checkbox list using below CSS, but unfortunately, it's not getting applied.

HTML

```
<body>
    <select size="5" name="lstStates" multiple="multiple" id="lstStates">
        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="NY">New York</option>
        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
      <option value="GG">asdfa</option>
      <option value="AW">jghjh</option>
      <option value="AE">qwer</option>
    </select>   
</body>
```

CSS

```
multiselect-container label input {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(function () { 
    $('#lstStates').multiselect({ 


    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/emozsaurab/ryo6b6g7/95/)

Comment: @Satpal — Generated by JS not included in the question.

Comment: So it was because you were missing `.` for class indicator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`multiselect-container` is a class, so your CSS should be

```
.multiselect-container label input {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
.multiselect-container > li > a > label > input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/k2oxgvuh/)

Answer (score 0):

Add the below CSS to your CSS and it should work as expected

```
.multiselect-container>li>a>label>input[type=checkbox] {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```